# Getting error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

Getting below error:

```
WARN   [08:21:24.175] [dw-397] o.e.j.s.HttpChannel -  //11.136.0.52:9999/devices 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I    
at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.updateResponses(InstrumentedHandler.java:291)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:254)
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:459)
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
```

I can see many suggestions are related to conflict in servlet-api jar version (like having 2.3 or having both 2.3 and 3.0 in pom or upgrade to 3.0 version). I checked in my pom having "servlet-api jar" with "3.1.0" only and didn't have any conflicts. Still I am facing this issue.

Please let me know, if any other jar is complicating this issue or may be any jar still need to remove or add.

Added dependency tree:

```
+- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-util:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jackson:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-configuration:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-logging:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-logback:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-metrics:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jersey:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-metainf-services:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jersey2:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-servlets:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jetty:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jetty9:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-lifecycle:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jmx:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.papertrail:profiler:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-request-logging:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-access:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.argparse4j:argparse4j:jar:0.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain.setuid:jetty-setuid-java:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-assets:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.5.0-b32:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.5.0-b32:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.5.0-b32:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.5.0-b32:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.5.0-b32:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:jar:0.13.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.7.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.7.4:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.7.4:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.7.4:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.7.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.7.4:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.7.4:test
[INFO] +- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.3:test
[INFO] +- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-matchers:jar:2.6.3:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:jar:1.3.7:test
[INFO] |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers:jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory:jar:2.25.1:test
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:jar:2.25.1:test
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:4.0.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-xpi-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:4.0.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:4.0.0-alpha-1:test
[INFO] |     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.12:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |     \- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO] |        \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.17.2:test
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver:jar:2.33.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:3.141.59:test
[INFO] |  \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.33:test
[INFO] |     +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |     |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.6:test
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.33:test
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:jar:2.33:test
[INFO] |     |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.0:test
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-cssparser:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |     +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.6:test
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:test
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:test
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:test
[INFO] |           \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-rfc7950:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-reactor:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-spi:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-util:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:openconfig-model-api:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-impl:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:odlext-model-api:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:odlext-parser-support:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:openconfig-parser-support:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:rfc6536-model-api:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:rfc6536-parser-support:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:rfc7952-model-api:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:rfc7952-parser-support:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:rfc8040-model-api:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:rfc8040-parser-support:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:rfc8528-model-api:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.opendaylight.yangtools:rfc8528-parser-support:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-api:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.opendaylight.yangtools:util:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- tech.pantheon.triemap:triemap:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.automation-remarks:video-recorder-junit:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |  \- com.automation-remarks:video-recorder-core:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |     +- org.zeroturnaround:zt-exec:jar:1.9:test
[INFO] |     +- org.aeonbits.owner:owner-java8:jar:1.0.9:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.aeonbits.owner:owner:jar:1.0.9:test
[INFO] |     \- org.awaitility:awaitility:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |        +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |        \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:jar:4.5.9:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
```

POM.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.9</httpclient.version>
        <xmlunit-matchers.version>2.6.3</xmlunit-matchers.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- test-scoped dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit-core</artifactId>
            <version>${xmlunit-matchers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit-matchers</artifactId>
            <version>${xmlunit-matchers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <!-- exclude commons-io because it is not only used in test -->
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-htmlunit-driver.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <!-- exclude commons-io because it is not only used in test -->
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>yang-common</artifactId>
            <version>${yangtools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>yang-parser-rfc7950</artifactId>
            <version>${yangtools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>yang-parser-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${yangtools.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>yang-parser-api</artifactId>
            <version>${yangtools.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>yang-model-api</artifactId>
            <version>${yangtools.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.automation-remarks</groupId>
            <artifactId>video-recorder-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
        <!-- excluded log4j because it is using 1.2.17 version which is vulnerability-->
         <groupId>log4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>../</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>${frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion}</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>${frontend-maven-plugin.npmVersion}</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- This plugin does not inject noproxy settings from settings.xml into npm, which seems to be a bug.
                                 When this is resolved, https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/887
                                 we can remove this workaround. Until then,
                                 to workaround this issue, we add a no_proxy environment variable to this command so
                                 we don't use the proxies for the registry-->
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        
        <profile>
            <id>karma-windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>Windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.kelveden</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-karma-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <karmaExecutable>${project.parent.basedir}/node/node ${project.parent.basedir}/node_modules/karma/bin/karma</karmaExecutable>
                            <configFile>../karma.conf.js</configFile>
                            <browsers>PhantomJS</browsers>
                            <autoWatch>false</autoWatch>
                            <singleRun>true</singleRun>
                            <colors>true</colors>
                            <skipKarma>false</skipKarma>
                            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                            <karmaFailureIgnore>false</karmaFailureIgnore>
                            <reporters>mocha,coverage,junit</reporters>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        
        <profile>
            <id>karma-linux</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>Linux</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.kelveden</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-karma-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <karmaExecutable>${project.parent.basedir}/node/node ../node_modules/.bin/karma</karmaExecutable>
                            <configFile>../karma.conf.js</configFile>
                            <browsers>PhantomJS</browsers>
                            <autoWatch>false</autoWatch>
                            <singleRun>true</singleRun>
                            <colors>true</colors>
                            <skipKarma>true</skipKarma>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                            <karmaFailureIgnore>false</karmaFailureIgnore>
                            <reporters>mocha,coverage,junit</reporters>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-tests</id>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${failsafe.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>add-test-source</id>
                                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                                    <goal>add-resource</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <sources>
                                        <source>src/it/java</source>
                                    </sources>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>stability-tests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${failsafe.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
                            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/BaseStabilityTest.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>add-test-source</id>
                                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <sources>
                                        <source>src/it/java</source>
                                        <source>src/stability/java</source>
                                    </sources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: Please include `mvn dependency:tree` result in your post

Comment: added dependency tree

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with same dropwizard version with jdk 1.8. Please provide more details(pom, jdk, how you trigger the error), or a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: We are using standalone application with java1.8 version, while running like Run as java application we are getting above error "Jetty Server". Attached POM.xml for reference.

Comment: Still cannot see your error using pom provided. Another suggestion is adding vm option `-verbose:class` when you run the application, then find the line in console started with: `[Loaded javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse from ` to see where does `HttpServletResponse` come from.

Answer (score 1):

I shall venture to say that the above error is looking like a classical jar shadowing problem. I am not sure when you are getting this, as you have not mentioned it, is it during compilation, testing or WAR deployment (my guess would be compilation/test).

The problem most likely stems from jersey-container-servlet-core getting included transitively. It declares a provided dependency on servlet API 2.4 which does not have the 'getStatus()' method defined (Refer: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730096/javax-servlet-http-httpservletresponse-getstatus-not-found)).

If 2.4 is on classpath, this will shadow (come before in path search) other jars containing javax.servlet package and it does not have the method required.

Also refer [aspects of Maven dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies). Refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874990/maven-transitive-dependencies-with-provided-scope), as to why this might not be turning up on the 'dependency:tree'.

One way out is to force use of the servlet jar above 2.4 (like 3.0, 3.01, ...) with a 'dependencyManagement' element in your pom and mention the version required.

## Added this section wrt the comments

Try adding a 'dependencyManagement' element to force the version:

```
<project>
    <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>3.0.1</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies><!-- Your current dependencies --></dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: We are not using 2.4 servlet-api version in any of the transitive dependency, we see in our code servlet-api version 3.1.0 is transitive dependency as part of dropwizard-core.  check once below transitive dependency hierarchy :   Dropwizard-core : 1.3.7[compile] --> dropwizard-jersey :1.3.7 [compile] ---> jetty-server : 9.4.11.v20180605[compile] --> javax.servlet-api : 3.1.0 [compile].  This error is occurring in local env while running standalone application right click --> Run as -> Java application.

Comment: You have dependency on jersey-container-servlet, which has compile dependency on jersey-container-servlet-core which has provided dependency on javax.servlet 2.4, refer (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet/2.25.1 and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/2.25.1). For you jersey-servlet is compile, for jersey-servlet jersey-servlet-core is compile, for jersey-servlet-core javax.servlet is provided, therefore javax.servlet is provided which will be there on classpath for compilation

Comment: Hi ironluca, I just added scope as provided for dropwizard-core dependency as below:<dependency>
   <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
   <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
   <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>  In dropwizard-core the transitive dependencies jersey-container-servlet and jersey-container-servlet-core both scope are provided now. jersey-container-servlet : 2.25.1[provided] --> jersey-container-servlet-core:2.25.1[provided]. But still facing the same error, Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Bhavitha, refer additions to my answer.

Comment: tried  'DependencyManagement' element, But still getting same error.

Comment: @Bhavitha, when are you getting this error, during compilation, testing or running the WAR

Comment: This is not war/ear application, It is standalone application while running the application like Rus as -- Java applications , we can see this URL "Start URL: http://localhost:8040/main.html" in console, when we are trying to access this URL in browser, we are facing this error.

Comment: Since it is not a standard build, it is difficult to determine the 'where' of the error. However, the reason that error is coming is older version of servlet-api jar is there in classpath. If you can track down and remove it, it should work. The jar file name would be servlet-api-x.x.jar, where x.x is the version, look for 2.4